# Create Divs for each group of values

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I need to group all rows with matching roomcode. When I also group resort, it acts like it disables the grouping of roomcode and only gives me the results of the first row with a roomcode.

How can I group the resort column and still group matching roomcode columns? If I ungroup my resort code the query works correctly, but then I can't create separate divs for differing resorts.

The user is searching a date range, hence having multiple rows with the same roomcode, which fetches my points. This is why I am getting the sum of those points. My current way of grouping each resort for output HTML purposes is breaking that. I don't necessarily have to group the resorts, I just need each room at each resort created within its own DIV set. I have a basic example below.

Ideal HTML output

```
<div id="results">
<div id="resort resortcode">
   <div id="roomresults">
       <div id="room1"></div>
       <div id="room2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="resort2 resortcode2">
   <div id="roomresults2">
       <div id="room3"></div>
       <div id="room4"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**This PHP code will group each set of results by resorts, but jacks up my price.**

```
<?php
include("dbh.php");
mysqli_select_db($con, "checkavail") or die ("no database");
$checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
$checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
$occupants = $_POST['occupants'];
$sqlCommand=
"SELECT
MIN(staydate) AS checkin,
MAX(staydate) AS lastnight,
MIN(available) AS available,
ra.resort AS resortcode,
ri.resort,
ri.room,
ri.roomcode,
ri.view,
SUM(ra.points*'20') AS price,
ri.sqfoot,
ri.description,
ri.bedding,
ri.amenities,
ri.sleeps,
ri.sleep_details,
ri.layout_img AS layoutimg,
ri.room_img AS roomimg,
ri.roomimg_thumb
FROM resort_availability AS ra
    LEFT JOIN room_info AS ri ON (ra.room = ri.roomcode)
WHERE staydate >= '$checkin' AND staydate = '$checkout'
AND sleeps >= '$occupants'
GROUP BY ri.roomcode
ORDER BY ri.resort, points
";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$data = array();


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $itemName = $row["resort"];
    $resortCode = $row["resortcode"];
    if ( !array_key_exists($itemName, $data)) {
        $data[$itemName] = array ();
    }
    $data[$itemName][] = $row;
}

foreach ($data as $itemName => $rows) {
  echo '<div class="resort ' ,$resortCode , '">';
  echo '<div class="resort_header"><h1>', $itemName, '</h1></div>';

  foreach ($rows as $row){ 
    if ($row['available'] > 0) {
    $roomresult = '<div class="room_result roomavailable">';
    $available = '<button class="available">BOOK NOW</button>';
    $filtavail = 'available';
}
else {
    $roomresult = '<div class="room_result roomsoldout" style="">';
    $available = '<button class="soldout">SOLD OUT</button>';
    $filtavail = 'soldout';
}


    echo $roomresult;
    echo '<div class="room_thumb"></div>
    <div class="room_info"><h4>'
    ,$row['room'], '-' ,$row['view'] ,
     '</h4></div>
    <div class="price"><center><h3>','' ,$row['price'],'</h3>' , $available ,'</center></div></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

[image]

**This PHP code gives me accurate results but does not allow me to Create a div with results based on each resort IE, I don't know how to create a Header with the resort name, separating each set of rooms by resort as it is in the first example.**

```
<?php
include("dbh.php");
mysqli_select_db($con, "checkavail") or die ("no database");
$checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
$checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
$occupants = $_POST['occupants'];
$sqlCommand=
"SELECT
MIN(staydate) AS checkin,
MAX(staydate) AS lastnight,
MIN(available) AS available,
ra.resort AS resortcode,
ri.resort AS resort,
ri.room,
ri.roomcode AS roomcode,
ri.view,
SUM(ra.points) AS points,
ri.sqfoot,
ri.description,
ri.bedding,
ri.amenities,
ri.sleeps,
ri.sleep_details,
ri.layout_img AS layoutimg,
ri.room_img AS roomimg,
ri.roomimg_thumb
FROM resort_availability AS ra
    LEFT JOIN room_info AS ri ON (ra.room = ri.roomcode)
WHERE staydate >= '$checkin' AND staydate < '$checkout'
AND sleeps >= '$occupants'
GROUP BY ri.resort, roomcode
ORDER BY ri.resort, points
";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($con));



while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$pricecalc = ($row['points'])*20;
$price = number_format($pricecalc, 2);




//RESULTS BOX
if($row['available'] < "1"){
    echo '<div id="'.$row['roomcode'].'-'.$row['resortcode'].'"','class="soldout roomresults room'.$row['resortcode'].'">';
}
if($row['available'] > "0"){
echo '<div id="'.$row['roomcode'].'-'.$row['resortcode'].'"','class="available roomresults room'.$row['resortcode'].'">';
}

//IMAGE BOX
    echo '<div class="thumbnail"><img height="90" src="',$row['roomimg_thumb'],'">';

    echo '</div>';


//ROOM DETAILS
    echo '<div class="roomdetails">';
    echo '<h4>'.$row['room'].' - '.$row['view'].'</h4>';
    echo '<p>Sleeps: '.$row['sleep_details'].'</p>';
    echo '<p class="clickfordetails">Click Image For Room Details</p>';
    echo '</div>';

//PRICING BOX AND SUBMIT BUTTON
    echo '<div class="price">';
        echo '<h3>$',$price,'</h3>';
        if ($row['available'] < "1"){
    echo '<button type="button" class="soldoutbtn">SOLD OUT</button>';
}
        if ($row['available'] > "0"){
    echo '<button type="button" class="booknowbtn">BOOK NOW</button>';
}
    
    echo '</div,$row>';
echo '</div></div>';

};

?>
```

[image]

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: And why would a user want to limit themselves to rooms with stay dates equal to their checkout date? Confused.

Comment: the price is determined by each night. The check-out day is excluded from this as they are not charged for the day they check out. Therefore, my query searches the check-in date through the day before the checkout dates, so the pricing is accurate. I have another setup of code I was playing with. Everything is accurate with it, it just doesn't allow me to group the resorts within the HTML output.

This code gives me the ability to group the resorts on output, but screws up my query results, for whatever reason, I have yet to understand.

Comment: And note that `WHERE... sleeps =...` renders this query as an INNER JOIN.

Comment: You are going to have to elaborate. I can parse this query as a json array and it gives me 100% correct results. So, I am not sure what you are going on about. I just need to figure out how to create a header for each resort and have room results from that resort listed within that div.

Comment: The issue seems to be with my lower PHP code below the query, as in my question both queries are the same and the PHP code to my second example gives me accurate results.

Comment: Your query executes an INNER JOIN so you can omit the LEFT keyword

Comment: I see what you are saying. My array looks the same. Still trying to figure out how to break these up by resort. So I can have resort headers above each section of rooms at each resort.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does one come up with a statement like `SUM(ra.points*'20')`? Where does the sophistication to enclose 20 in inverted commas come from?

Comment: I'm very new to a lot of this. I am just lucky that I can output it. As for the SUM line, I was testing to see if I could do my math within the query to create a variable.

Comment: Is your entire purpose to pick through everything, and not help with the question at hand? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `group by` will give you the 1st record of the same group.

In my understanding , you want to show all the data but place all the records with the same roomcode together.

In that case, please change

```
GROUP BY ri.roomcode
ORDER BY ri.resort, points
```

to

```
ORDER BY ri.roomcode, ri.resort, points
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm gonna have to sleep on this and report back tomorrow with an updated question. I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: I updated the question with a second set of code and some screenshots to help explain.